# Unable to empty BarChart

Tags: javafx

I have a method that gets the data from a sorted list and puts it in to a bar chart. I uses the exact same code for a piechart, and the piechart works fine.. But for the bar chart, when the sorted list changes the bar chart refuses to clear the old data?

```
private void getBarChartData() {
    series1.getData().clear(); <----- tried this, doesn't help

    for (Record record : sortedData) {
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(record.getFieldMonth(), record.getFieldValue()));
    }
    barChart.getData().addAll(series1);

}
```

My code for the piechart is

```
private void getPieChartData() {
    pieChart.getData().clear();

    for (Record record : sortedData) {
        dataList.add(new PieChart.Data(record.getFieldMonth(), record.getFieldValue()));
    }
    pieChart.setData(dataList);

}
```

Comment: Your error is probably elsewhere in your code. Can you build a minimal, complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You keep adding series to the bar chart where you want to be replacing series in the chart so that old series are removed.

Replace:

```
barChart.getData().addAll(series1);
```

With:

```
barChart.setData(FXCollections.observableArrayList(series1));
```

Comment: This worked, It's pretty obvious, but needed you to pointed me in the right direction, thanks !